# Image sizes for slicing on Android Tablets?

Tags: android, tablet

I have to slice text boxes and give it to developers. What are the image sizes that I have to follow to slice them for the various resolutions for tablets (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi, etc.)?

Comment: Might be helpful, http://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter/

Comment: I've reworded and retitled your question to make it more readable.  Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a calculator a long time ago that calculates the sizes, see [DP Calculator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidfactorem.dpimagecalculator)